# ngx-translate localization files are not found when using a custom baseHref

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nginx, ngx-translate

For our application, we are using `ngx-translate` to localize all the texts. We are putting this application on a server, and in order to access it, we use a Nginx location (`/my-location`).

In order to make this location work, we had to set the `--base-href /my-location/` flag in our `build` command, and to add this line to our `app.module.ts` file :

```
{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/my-location/'},
```

Even if the location works properly, all the localized texts appear as their keys and not their translations (`welcomeMessage` appears, whilst it should be "Welcome!").

I have tried adding a custom path to the `TranslateHttpLoader`

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient): TranslateHttpLoader {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient): TranslateHttpLoader {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/');
}
```

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient): TranslateHttpLoader {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, '../assets/i18n/');
}
```

...but to no avail. It should be noted that all translations work on my local environment (if I don't add any of the above configuration). If I use any of the above configurations in my local environment, I get this error :

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:3000/api/assets/i18n/en.json
```

It seems to be wrongly trying to load the translation files from the server...